# Interval of Validity of a Solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

> By separation of variables, the general solution to $y' = 3y - y^2$ is
>
> $y(t) = 0$ or $y(t) = \frac{3}{1+ce^{-3t}}$.
>
> Find the interval of validity of the solution satisfying $y(0) = 6$.
>
> (i.e. find $a$ and $b$ such that the solution is valid on the interval $a<t<b$.)

I'm not really sure how to approach this.
I set $y' = 0$ and hence $3y - y^2 = 0$, and assuming $y \neq 0$, I proceeded to $3 = y = \frac{3}{1+ce^{-3t}}$. Then $1=1+ce^{-3t}$, which means $c=0$ since any $e^x$ function will never be $0$.

However, this entirely gets rid of the term containing $t$, and doesn't help me find boundaries for $t$.

How should I approach/solve this?

Comment: $y$ is not even a function of $t$?

Comment: Well, it could be a function of $t$, when $y(t) = 3/(1+ce^{-3t})$— I'm sorry, I had a typo there!

Comment: I hope that I've now caught all my errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you found the non-stationary solution of the ODE $y'(t)=3y(t)-y^2(t)$:
$$y(t) = \frac{3}{1+ce^{-3t}}$$
where $c$ is a real value different from zero.
The interval of validity depends on the initial condition $y(t_0)=y_0$. If $t_0=0$ and $y_0=6$ then
$$6=y(0) = \frac{3}{1+ce^{-3\cdot 0}}=\frac{3}{1+c}$$
which implies that $c=-1/2$.
Hence the solution that passes through the initial point $(0,6)$ is 
$$y(t) = \frac{3}{1-\frac{e^{-3t}}{2}}=\frac{6}{2-e^{-3t}}$$
which is not defined for all real values of $t$.
The interval of validity of the solution is the biggest interval in the domain which contains $t=0$. Can you take it from here?

P.S. Note that if the initial condition is $y(t_0)=y_0$ with $y_0\in (0,3)$, i.e. between the stationary solutions that it will turn out that the interval of validity is whole real line $\mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, for $y_0$ outside the interval $[0,3]$, as in your case, the  interval of validity is just a half-line.

Comment: Yes! That helped a lot, thank you.

Comment: But I do have a question—am I wrong in thinking that I could solve IVP by finding the critical points of $y'$? (in other words, finding solutions to $y'=0$?

Comment: No, finding the stationary solutions (i.e. when $y'$ is identically zero) is helpful. Note that if $y(0)=3$ then we find immediately that the solution is the stationary solution $y(t)=3$.